# Is it possible to place a gist on a wordpress.com site?

Tags: github, wordpress.com

Is it possible to place a gist on a wordpress.com site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible because wordpress.com does not allow for either custom plugins or insertion of Javascript code.

It would be possible on a standalone site using the wordpress.org software.